# Интерация чисел, пока не станет 1

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию JavaScript,которая возьмет число,и сложит квадрат каждой его цифры, пока не станет 1, если конечно с этим числом это возможно. Например:

> x=23 -> 2^2+3^2=13 -> 1^2+3^2=10 -> 1^2+0^2=1

Числа могут быть разными, например 0, 1, 12, 123, 1234...
Если задано такое число, что в конце станет 1, то пусть возвращает true, а если нет - false.
(Не использовать prototype.)
Я написал что-то такое, но это работает неправильно, так как это для двузначных чисел (10-99)

```js
function solution5(x) {
  let a;
  let b;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    a = Math.floor(x / 10)
    b = (x / 10) % 1 * 10
    x = a ** 2 + b ** 2
    if (x == 1) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
console.log(solution5(10))
```

Comment: это и для двух цифровых не работает. Вообще в предоставленном коде какая-то другая задача решается

Comment: Но ведь у вас этот код не правильно работает.

Comment: ну да,а что делать чтоб было правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неоптимальный с точки зрения производительности вариант, можно и быстрее: :)

```js
function sum2(num) {
  return (num + '').split('').map(n => parseInt(n)).filter(isFinite).reduce((acc, n) => acc += n * n, 0);
}

function check(num) {
  let count = 0;
  let max = -Infinity;
  let cur = num;
  do {
    cur = sum2(cur);
    if (cur > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) throw 'Loss of precision, unable to calculate';
    if (cur == 1) return true;
    if (cur > max) max = cur;
    count++;
  } while (count < max)
  return false;
}

console.log(0, check(0));
console.log(1, check(1));
console.log(12, check(12));
console.log(23, check(23));
console.log(123, check(123));
console.log(1234, check(1234));
```

Оптимизированный вариант:

```js
function sum2(num) {
  return (num + '').split('').map(n => parseInt(n)).filter(isFinite).reduce((acc, n) => acc += n * n, 0);
}

function check(num) {
  let used = new Set();
  let cur = num;
  do {
    cur = sum2(cur);
    if (used.has(cur)) return false;
    if (cur == 1) return true;
    if (cur > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) throw 'Loss of precision, unable to calculate';
    used.add(cur);
  } while (true)
}

console.log(0, check(0));
console.log(1, check(1)); 
console.log(12, check(12));
console.log(23, check(23));
console.log(123, check(123));
console.log(1234, check(1234));
```

Строго говоря, в обоих вариантах проверка на `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` не особо нужна, потому что даже если передать в функцию `sum2` число, записанное в виде достаточно длинной строки, превысить это значение не удастся (строка необходимой для этого длины не поместится в памяти), однако пусть будет, для полноты картины.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам ваша функция, но зацикливать я ее не стал бы. Вешает компьютер.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('number');
const result = document.getElementById('result');
var sum;
function count() {
  var number = input.value;
  let array = number.toString().split('');
  sum = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    sum += Math.pow(array[i],2);
  }
  result.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', sum + '<br>');
  
  //console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number">
<button onclick="count()">count</button>
<h4>result</h4>
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: но так он делает только один раз,то есть - input 23,result 13,input 13 result 10,но надо делать input 23,result 1,то есть  true.

Comment: дело в том, что значение не дает 1, то можно и повесить моей функцией. Решение от @Yaant работает. Хотя конечно накрученное )

Comment: да,но а если сказать что-то вроде этого - while(sum!=1) {
      sum += Math.pow(x[i],2);
    }

Comment: Да )) и он на некоторых числах будет крутиться вечно.

Comment: для этих будем написать if else )))

Comment: Да нет, он не выйдет из цикла. Можно проверить, если итераций больше 10 вернуть false. Либо записывать результаты и если они повторились вернуть false

Comment: как это проверить?

Comment: в моем примере попробуйте поиграть с разными значениями, и результаты вводите. Или как проверить цифры введенные ранее? Если так, то создать временный массив и как только indexOf вернет не -1 вернуть false

Comment: ладно,спасибо вам большое))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88953/discussion-between-tyom-arshakyan-and-ruslan-semenov).