# Сложение квадратов цифр числах, пока не станет 1

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию, которая возьмет число, и сложит квадрат каждой его цифры, пока не станет 1, если конечно с этим числом это возможно. Например:

> x=23 -> 2^2+3^2=13 -> 1^2+3^2=10 -> 1^2+0^2=1 -> true
>
> x=22 -> 2^2+2^2=8 -> false

Числа могут быть разными, например 0, 1, 12, 123, 1234...
Если задано такое число, что в конце станет 1, то пусть возвращает true, а если нет - false.
Есть и такие числа, которые бесконечно будут повторять действие, тогда, когда в какой-то части будет повторятся одно и те-же цифры. В током случае тоже пуст возвращает false.
(Не использовать prototype.) В моих примерах коды делают это только один раз. Наверно нужно делать по циклу while (Например: while (x!=1){...}), но не знаю как.

> код 1

```
function solution(x) {
  let s=0;
  x = x.toString().split('');
  for (let i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    s += Math.pow(x[i],2);
  }
   if (s==1) {
      return true
    }
    return false
}
console.log(solution(23));
```

> код 2

```
function solution(x) {
let y;
    y=(x + '').split('')
              .map(b => parseInt(b))
              .reduce((a,b) => a += b * b, 0);
    if (y==1) {
      return true
    }
    return false
}
  console.log(solution(23));
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Интерация чисел, пока не станет 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/938036/%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-1)

Comment: А чем не устроили ответы к предыдущему такому же вопросу?

Comment: так-как я учусь,предыдущие ответы были не так понятны для меня,этот раз ответ был абсолютно понятным)

Comment: предыдущий думал удалить,но читал правила про удалении вопроса,и задал новый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в целом правильная логика для решения такой задачи, единственное что если неизвестно заранее количество итераций, которое необходимо совершить, то имеет смысл использовать **Рекурсивный подход** с указанием условия, когда нужно завершить повторный вызов функции:

```js
            function test(value) {
                if (value.toString().length == 1) {
                    if (value == 1) {
                        console.log(value);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        console.log(value);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                value = value.toString().split("");
                value = value
                    .map(e => Number(e) * Number(e))
                    .reduce((accum, e) => accum + e);
                return test(value);
            }

            test(23);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое